# issue with jquery 'select' variable change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$('select').change(function (evt) {
    checkSelectAllOthers($(this).attr('id'), optionValues);
    optionValues = $('option:selected', this).map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
}).trigger('change');
function checkSelectAllOthers(select, optionValues) {
    if ($("#" + select + " option").length == 1) {
        return;
    }
    var allValue = 'All';
    var allOption = $("#" + select + " option:not([value])");
    var otherOptions = $("#" + select).find("option[value!='0']", " option:not([value])");
    var newOptionValues = $('option:selected', $("#" + select)).map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    if ($.inArray(allValue, optionValues) != $.inArray(allValue, newOptionValues)) {
        //The 'All' option is clicked
        if ($(allOption).is(":checked")) {
            $(otherOptions).each(function () {
                $(this).attr('selected', true);
            });
            $("#" + select).multiselect({
                selectedList: 1100
            });
            $("#" + select).multiselect('refresh');
        } else {
            $(otherOptions).each(function () {
                $(this).attr('selected', false);
            });
            $("#" + select).multiselect({
                selectedList: 1000
            });
            $("#" + select).multiselect('refresh');
        }
    } else {
        var selectSize = $("#" + select + " option").length;
        if (optionValues.length == selectSize && newOptionValues.length == selectSize - 1) {
            //deselect 'All'
            $(allOption).attr('selected', false);
            $("#" + select).multiselect({
                selectedList: 1000
            });
            $("#" + select).multiselect('refresh');
        } else if (newOptionValues.length == selectSize - 1) {
            //all other options are selected so set 'All' as selected
            $(allOption).attr('selected', true);
            $("#" + select).multiselect({
                selectedList: 1100
            });
            $("#" + select).multiselect('refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

The above code get all the selects in the page and if "All" checkbox is selected, it will select all checkboxes.

It works but **when the 'select' variable is null or undefined**, there is an error in the console in developer tools which is:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #jquery.js:869 jQuery.extend._Deferred.deferred.resolveWithjquery.js:420 jQuery.extend.readyjquery.js:1055 DOMContentLoaded

After above error all js code stop running.

is there anything that I can check the 'select' is not null or undefined?

Comment: Please post your `checkSelectAllOthers` function code. Moreover `.trigger('change')` may cause a loop..

Comment: @DrKey I posted the function. I removed .trigger('change') it fixed the issue. Thank you

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @DrKey no, triggering a change on page load will not cause a loop. Is common practice to trigger an event handler right after creating it

Comment: do all the select elements in page have an ID? If not don't call `checkSelectAllOthers` if id doesn't exist. Also you are calling that function before assigning value to one of it's arguments `optionValues`. Order is wrong

Comment: You have right @charlietfl, my mistake..